# Update MySql database record in while loop with ajax - updates only first row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I click on button "Upisi" it works fine for the first record, bt on all other records it won't work.

ocitanja.php:

```html
<?php
include_once("header.php");
require("spajanje.php");
if(!isset($_POST["ulica"]))
{
 header('Location: index.php');
}
else $_SESSION["ulica"] = $_POST["ulica"];
echo "Očitač: " . $_SESSION["ocitac"] . "</br></br>";
echo "<form action='ulica.php'><input type='submit' value='Odabir ulice'></br></br>Odabrana ulica:</br>" . $_POST['ulica'] . "</form>";
echo "</br></br>";
?>
<table>
<?php
$korisnici = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ocitanja WHERE ocitac ='".$_SESSION["ocitac"]."' AND ulica ='".$_POST["ulica"]."'");

while ($row = $korisnici->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr><td><b>" . $row['prezime_ime'] . "</b></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Kućni broj: <b>" . $row['kbr'] . "</b></td></tr>";
    echo "<form><tr><td>
  <label>Broj plinomjera: </label><input type='text' id='bb' size='8' disabled value = '". $row['bb'] ."'></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Zadnje očitanje: " . $row['staro_stanje'] . " m<sup>3</sup></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>
  <label>Očitanje: </label>
  <input id='ocitanje' type='text' size='6' value = '". $row['ocitanje'] ."'> m<sup>3</sup>
  <input onclick='myFunction()' type='button' value='Upisi'>
  </td></tr></form>";
}
?>

</table>
<?php
include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

ajax.js.php:

```html
<?php
$bb2 = $_POST['bb1'];
$ocitanje2 = $_POST['ocitanje1'];
require("spajanje.php");
if (isset($_POST['ocitanje1'])) {
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ocitanja SET ocitanje='$ocitanje2' WHERE bb='$bb2'"); //Insert Query
    echo "Uspješno upisano očitanje!";
}
?>
```

script.js:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var bb = document.getElementById("bb").value;
    var ocitanje = document.getElementById("ocitanje").value;
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'bb1=' + bb + '&ocitanje1=' + ocitanje;
    if (ocitanje == '') {
        alert("Unesi očitanje!");
    } else {
// AJAX code to submit form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxjs.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any other ideas how to update every record separately in while loop? But without refreshing the page.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know where exactly the problem is but I can see where some issues might arise.

First, [IDs are unique](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180) as in two elements should not have the same IDs. That can be a reason why it is not working correctly as you are always using the same pair of elements into your AJAX call. So let's turn them into classes.

Second, let's [leverage jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler) since you are using it. If you are using this library, there's really no reason to ever use `onclick` (or any other event) attribute. Let's remove that attribute on your button and instead give it a class e.g. `upisi` that we'll be referencing shortly.

Third, you cannot have `<form/>` tag placed in between `<tr/>`. That is invalid HTML. Since we don't need, remove it. If you want to group `<tr/>` elements, use [`<tbody/>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp) element.

```
while ($row = $korisnici->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr><td><b>" . $row['prezime_ime'] . "</b></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Kućni broj: <b>" . $row['kbr'] . "</b></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>
        <label>Broj plinomjera: </label><input type='text' class='bb' size='8' disabled value = '". $row['bb'] ."'></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Zadnje očitanje: " . $row['staro_stanje'] . " m<sup>3</sup></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>
        <label>Očitanje: </label>
        <input class='ocitanje' type='text' size='6' value='". $row['ocitanje'] ."'> m<sup>3</sup>
        <input type='button' value='Upisi' class='upisi'>
        </td></tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
}
```

Now, in your JavaScript, let's attach an `onclick` event handler to the `.upisi` buttons.

```
$('.upisi').click(function () {
    // find bb and ocitange relative to the tbody
    var tbody = $(this).closest('tbody');
    // var bb = tbody.find('.bb').val(), ocitanje = tbody.find('.ocitanje').val();
    var bb = $('.bb', tbody).val(), ocitanje = $('.ocitanje', tbody).val();

    alert('bb: ' + bb + ', ocitanje: ' + ocitanje);

    if (ocitanje == '') {
        alert('Unesi očitanje!');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxjs.php',
            data: { bb1: bb, ocitanje1: ocitanje }, // cleaner
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Last, you should always check whether you have the POSTed fields before using them.

```
<?php
require("spajanje.php");
if (isset($_POST['bb1'], $_POST['ocitanje1'])) {
    $bb2 = $_POST['bb1'];
    $ocitanje2 = $_POST['ocitanje1'];
    if (mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ocitanja SET ocitanje='$ocitanje2' WHERE bb='$bb2'")) {
        echo "Uspješno upisano očitanje!";
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong"; // I have no idea what language you are using, so I'm not even going to try
    }
}
?>
```

Side-remark: you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in your PHP. As it is outside the scope of your problem, I have not included it.

Comment: Thanks for you help, it's working now when I put js code to ocitanja.php

Answer (score 1):

> **Problem**

Issue is simple.
In ocitanjia.php, in this line:

```
        <label>Broj plinomjera: </label><input type='text' id='bb' size='8' disabled value = '". $row['bb'] ."'></td></tr>";
```

every input field have the same id ('bb'), so in script.js, when you call this statement:

```
    var ocitanje = document.getElementById("ocitanje").value;
```

jQuery will return the **value of first text box** since this is how  jQuery behaves when it encounters multiple elements with same id.

> **Solution**
>   Though many things need to be corrected. Shortest way is to do this:
>   In ocitanjia.php, change this

```
echo "<tr><td>
    <label>Očitanje: </label>
    <input id='ocitanje' type='text' size='6' value = '". $row['ocitanje'] ."'> m<sup>3</sup>
    <input onclick='myFunction()' type='button' value='Upisi'>
    </td></tr></form>";
```

to this:

```
echo "<tr><td>
    <label>Očitanje: </label>
    <input id='ocitanje' type='text' size='6' value = '". $row['ocitanje'] ."'> m<sup>3</sup>
    <input onclick='myFunction(\'". $row['bb'] ."\')' type='button' value='Upisi'>
    </td></tr></form>";
```

AND in script.js change this:

```
function myFunction() {
var bb = document.getElementById("bb").value;
```

to this:

```
function myFunction(bb) {
```

Explanation: Pass value of bb as a parameter to the function that will pass unique value of bb every time the function is called